# Unexpected behavior in async method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I am currently experiencing some unexpected/unwanted behavior with an aync method I am trying to use. The async method is `RecognizeAsync`. I am unabled to await this method since it returns void. What is happening, is that `ProcessAudio` method will be called first and will seemingly run to completion however the webpage never returns my "Contact" view as it should or errors out. After the method runs to completion, the breakpoints in my handlers start being hit. If I let it play through to completion, no redirect will ever happen- in the network tab in chrome debugger, the "status" will stay marked as pending and just hang there. I believe my issue is being caused by issues with asynchronousity but have been unable to found out what exactly it is.

All help is appreciated.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> ProcessAudio()
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine speechEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    speechEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/AudioAssets/speechSample.wav"));
    var grammar = new DictationGrammar();
    speechEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);

    speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognizedHandler);
    speechEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(SpeechHypothesizedHandler);

    speechEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    return View("Contact", vm); //first breakpoint hit occurs on this line
                                  //but it doesnt seem to be executed? 
}

private void SpeechRecognizedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some work
    //3rd breakpoint is hit here
}

private void SpeechHypothesizedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //do some different work
    //2nd breakpoint is hit here
}
```

UPDATE: based on suggestions, I have changed my code to (in ProcessAudio):

```
using (speechEngine)
{
    speechEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(Server.MapPath("~/Content/AudioAssets/speechSample.wav"));
    var grammar = new DictationGrammar();
    speechEngine.LoadGrammar(grammar);

    speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognizedHandler);
    speechEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(SpeechHypothesizedHandler);
    var tcsRecognized = new TaskCompletionSource<EventArgs>();
    speechEngine.RecognizeCompleted += (sender, eventArgs) => tcsRecognized.SetResult(eventArgs);

    speechEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    try
    {
        var eventArgsRecognized = await tcsRecognized.Task;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw (e);
    }
}
```

and this is resulting in some wrong behavior:
The `return View("Contact",vm)` breakpoint will now be hit AFTER the handlers are finished firing however there is still no redirect that ever happens. I am never directed to my Contact page. I just si ton my original page indefinitely just like before.

Comment: Why not `await speechEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);`?

Comment: compiler error when trying to `await` an async method that returns void

Comment: @ErikPhilips It's old-style event-based asyncrony which uses a naming convention that intersects with the newer style TAP-based asynchrony. `WebClient` also shares this unfortunate naming clash.

Comment: @spender eeeeew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone is curious- i solved my issue by doing the following:

I changed to using `Recognize()` instead of `RecognizeAsync(..)` which lead to `InvalidOperationException` due to async events trying to be executed at an "invalid time in the pages lifecycle". To overcome this, I wrapped my operations in a thread and joined the thread back to the main thread directly after running it. Code below:

```
using (speechEngine)
      {
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
          speechEngine.SetInputToWaveFile(@"C:\AudioAssets\speechSample.wav");
          speechEngine.LoadGrammar(dictationGrammar);

          speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(SpeechRecognizedHandler);
          speechEngine.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(SpeechHypothesizedHandler);
          speechEngine.Recognize();
        });
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

      }
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

You're going too early. The speech engine probably hasn't even started by the time you hit the `return View` line.

You need to wait until the final event is fired from the speech engine. The best approach would be to convert from the event based asynchrony to [TAP-based asynchrony](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx).

This can be achieved by using [`TaskCompletionSource<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx)

Let's deal with (what I believe) should be the last event to fire after `speechEngine.RecognizeAsync` is called, i.e. `SpeechRecognized`. I'm assuming that this is the event that fires when the final result has been calculated by the speech engine.

So, first:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<EventArgs>();
```

now lets hook it up to complete when `SpeechRecognized` is fired, using inline lambda-style method declaration:

```
speechEngine.SpeechRecognized += (sender, eventArgs) => tcs.SetResult(eventArgs);
```

(...wait... what happens if no speech was recognized? We'll also need to hook up the `SpeechRecognitionRejected` event and define a custom Exception subclass for this type of event... here I'll just call it `RecognitionFailedException`. Now we're trapping all possible outcomes of the recognition process, so we would hope that the `TaskCompletionSource` would complete in all outcomes.)

```
speechEngine.SpeechRecognitionRejected += (sender, eventArgs) => 
                            tcs.SetException(new RecognitionFailedException());
```

then

```
speechEngine.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

now, we can `await` the `Task` property of our `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
try
{
    var eventArgs = await tcs.Task;
}
catch(RecognitionFailedException ex)
{
    //this would signal that nothing was recognized
}
```

do some processing on the EventArgs that is the Task's result, and return a viable result back to the client.

In the process of doing this, you are creating `IDisposable` instances that will need to be properly disposed.

So:

```
using(SpeechRecognitionEngine speechEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine())
{
    //use the speechEngine with TaskCompletionSource
    //wait until it's finished
    try
    {
        var eventArgs = await tcs.Task;
    }
    catch(RecognitionFailedException ex)
    {
        //this would signal that nothing was recognized
    }

} //dispose
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your suggested changes. Please see issues I'm having with it. Is that the implementation you had in mind?

Comment: @peggy I'm assuming that this is because there is more than one `SpeechHypothesized` event. Can you ditch your attempts to deal with the `SpeechHypothesized` event and just deal with the events outlined in my answer (i.e. those that represent a **final** result, not some sort of intermediate result) If that gets you somewhere, we can figure out how to deal with the `SpeechHypothesized` events.

Comment: I have updated my current attempt again. Now getting the handlers to fire before the view is trying to be returned (and all my models and my vm seem to be perfect) but I am still not getting a redirect to the contact page for some reason

Comment: @peggy I didn't know much about the SpeechRecognitionEngine when writing this answer. What's clear is that the actual "all done" event that you should be waiting for is `RecognizeCompleted`. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554584(v=vs.110).aspx) documents the order of events in the "remarks" section.

Comment: I have updated once more to include the using statement and try/catch. no exception is being thrown and I am still not getting redirected to my contact page unfortunately. I am also now waiting on `RecognizeCompleted`